# Programming MCU with ISP out of board

Tags: avr, atmega, isp

My MCU(ATMega328) configured to get clock from ext. oscillator. Can I still program this MCU without external oscillator using ISP, by just connecting 6 pins to `MISO/MOSI/SCK/RST/GND/VCC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. From the datasheet:

> Depending on CKSEL Fuses, a valid clock must be present.

This microcontroller needs a running clock to program flash memory, it reads, interprets and validates data received on MOSI line. If you program a CKSEL fuse to use external oscillator, microcontroller expects clock pulses to come from XTAL pins, if you don't provide these pulses, it can not function.

---

Edit:
you can add crystall and caps on a breadboard to program a chip out of the board